# Test Android DecimalFormat with Robolectric

Tags: java, android, robolectric, decimalformat

The Android library modified the [DecimalFormat class](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) with some nice additions. Of course, I need one of those additions (the signifant digit notation: `@`).

When I'm testing with Robolectric, it seems that the standard Java [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class is used, which makes my tests fail.

Is there a way to tell Robolectric to use the Android version? Or should I include `DecimalFormat` in my project (copy/pasting the class from AOSP?)?

Here's a stripped down example:

If I run the App on a device with the following:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = (DecimalFormat)java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
        decimalFormat.applyPattern("@@@");
        Log.d('SO', decimalFormat.format(0.0567467));
    }
}
```

It displays:

> W/App: 0.0567

In the Unit tests:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricGradleTestRunner;
import org.robolectric.annotation.Config;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertEquals;


@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21)
public class NumberFormatTest {
    @Test
    public void testSignificantDigit() {
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = (DecimalFormat)java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
        decimalFormat.applyPattern("@@@");
        assertEquals("0.0567", decimalFormat.format(0.0567467));
    }
}
```

Running the test will output:

> junit.framework.ComparisonFailure:
>
> Expected :0.0567
>
> Actual   :@@@0

Comment: define: *makes my tests fail* , *with some nice additions* ... add some code ...

Comment: Show us a minimum test that exhibits the problem. It will be a seed for a useful answer. Include any robolectric attributes on the test class.

Comment: since format() returns a StringBuffer, have you tried calling toString on it?

Comment: @Selvin *with some nice additions*l link to the actual Android addition was in the original question. But you're right, I've added a simple test case to illustrate the issue.

Comment: @Shine, the method signature is `final String  format(double value)`. There are other format methods that return a `StringBuilder` but they are not the ones I've used. I've nonetheless tried `toString()` but the test has the same failure.

Comment: Reproduced and asked https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2071

Answer (score 0):

As the [official android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) states, the implementation offered when running your java code in an Android RunTime (ART) differs from the one in a regular JVM.

RoboElectric does not run tests on a regular android phone or an emulator but on a JVM instead. This JVM, running on your host system, does not have this modified runtime implementation version of DecimalFormat. Therefore as far as I know the functionality Android offers is not available when running your test code in a JVM. To be able to use it, run your tests on an android phone, but then you may get rid of RoboElectric for that test anyway but use the [offered testing tools](https://developer.android.com/tools/testing/index.html).

Another logical question: Why do you want to test Android classes? I guess Google already wrote tests for there changes and keeps track of that, so [you should no test functionality offered to you by the system you're using](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/dont-test-blindly-the-right-methods-for-unit-testing-your-java-apps/).

Comment: This is exactly the question:
*Is there a way to tell Robolectric to use the Android version? Or should I include DecimalFormat in my project (copy/pasting the class from AOSP?)?*

The provided example is trivial, it is only there to exhibits the behaviour of the failure. My app has a complex number formatting scheme. I want to be sure that the right one is selected in the right case. 

I have another set of tests that runs on Espresso but my gut feeling tells me that number formatting belongs to Unit Tests.

Comment: If you want to make sure the correct format is selected, test that! Your test then should make sure that the correct format string is selected/returned by your "selectCorrectFormat" function. No need to test the formatting itself, as this is part of android system.

Comment: You may not need to use another third party library like espresso but can use  [Android Instrumented Unit tests](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html)

Comment: Yep, that's what i've ended up with: testing the pattern generation. But that makes for ugly non readable unit tests. They don't make any sense for the scientists glancing at the tests (which they do a lot since the app is heavy on computation). It's like testing regex, I like to add some example/corner case just for illustration.